# insert when there are special characters including single quotes and double quotes

Tags: mysql

I am trying to run the SQL below:

```
INSERT INTO `AmazonPriceLog`(
    `CreatedDt`,
    `Title`
)
VALUES(
    CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    'This isn't a good test of a quote said by a famous person "wow" MySQL won;t work'
)
```

but getting this error:

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 't a good test of a quote said by a famous person "wow" MySQL won' at line 7

I know this is related to the quotes and I have tried using the Quote function but still getting errors. I cannot make this a parameterized query due to limitations of how I am integration this insert statement.

Any suggestions? Ideally, the solution would be dynamic and doesn't involve manually escaping characters.

Comment: What is building the dynamic query?

Comment: You say you're using a quote function, but it can't be a good quote function since it's not doing the one thing it needs to do to be a quote function. You haven't described the code, or even the language it is, so no one can recommend anything specific to fix it.

Comment: @AAA You should better explain the limits you mention and the general environment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to escape special charachters with backslash, in your case: `'This isn\'t a good test of a quote said by a famous person "wow" MySQL won;t work'`.

And I imagine that `won;t` can became `won\'t`.

Many languages have function that escape strings for you, or better can prepare queries with parameters and when you pass the parameters they are automatically escaped.